# React Native: How do I manage the 9000 Android screen sizes?

Tags: android, react-native

I just built the most insanely awesome complicated app over the course of the last 6 months for both iOS and Android using React native.

Everything was going perfect, and everything is working great...

I designed for iPhone 4s, 5, 6, 6+ using a special component I wrote which basically works like...

```
override: {
  ip4: { fontSize: 8 },
  ip5: { fontSize: 10 }
}
```

etc.

This actually worked **perfect** for iOS.

Today I opened up GA and was terrified to realize I forgot to style Android. I looked at our Google analytics and there's literally like... 700 screen sizes that are all different.

I'm utterly confused at the prospect of designing for all these, especially considering theres multiple pixel densities.

My question is, WHAT do I actually do to account for...

- margins / spacings (basically generic integers for padding or whatever)
- font sizes

Those are the 2 things I'm very confused how to handle all the different combinations.

I've taken a look at `PixelRatio`, but I have no idea how to use it or even if I'm on the right track.

How do most people handle this?

Comment: checked back on this hoping there would be an intelligent answer. Have you worked out a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both Dimensions and PixelRatio to get the screen dimensions and pixels.
I use this for example to set image sizing based on the screen size..

For example:

```
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import PixelRatio from 'PixelRatio';

var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
var pixelr = PixelRatio.get();

// Calculate styles, heights, fontsizes based on the numbers above
```

Comment: Can you complete the answer, noone really knows how to use the `PixelRatio` for both iOS and  Android. Have you done this yourself?

Comment: @SudoPlz just multiply by pixelr.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Media Queries for manage the multiple screen sizes , I was use media queries concept in my phonecap (cordova) in earlier stage of development.

I have find on tutorial while searching, I think it's helpful,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive

Answer (score 0):

We ended tyo use flexboxes all around the app. So the content accomodate itselfs when space is available.

Of course, we lost whole days on trying and testing